# Go local imports with CI

Tags: git, go, gogs

I understand Go is pretty opinionated about local import paths.

I have a CI/Git server set up with Gogs and Drone - lets call it `ci.company.corp`
when requiring files locally I would write something like this:

`import 'ci.company.corp/seangregory/project/server/models'`

I'd like to use glide to manage packages, but I'll keep it simple for now.

I can push this code to Gogs, and in turn "go get ci.company.corp/seangregory/project"  but when I try to build using drone in a docker container, it can't resolve the sub directories from the local imports.

Are each of these sub-directories supposed to be a git submodule?  is it an issue with Gogs?

Comment: I don't think each of the sub-directories need to be git submodules. I have created and used local go packages that were written adhoc without version control.